# Resolving "HttpAdaptor JMXInvokerServlet is accessible to unauthenticated remote users" vulnerability

Tags: security, http

Recently our security info team has determined there is a vulnerability in one of our systems.

Vulnerability description:

> JBoss HttpAdaptor JMXInvokerServlet is Accessible to Unauthenticated Remote Users

Googling on this didn't provide much information. How can we resolve the issue?

Comment: This what I got in one of the forum.                            Above vulnerability means, any GET or POST requests are blocked and receive a 401 error. 
 
The HTTP protocol includes other verbs besides GET and POST, for instance HEAD, PUT and DELETE. These verbs will be executed by the GET handler because they are not listed in the security constraint. 
To prevent the remaining verbs from triggering the GET handler. The explicit denial of GET and POST must be removed. This will block all verbs by default.    Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2):

JBoss comes with several admin access points that need to be secured or removed to prevent unauthorized access to admin functions in a deployment. The following sections describe the various admin services and how to secure them.

**The *jmx-console.war* Service**

The jmx-console.war found in the deploy directory provides an HTML view into the JMX microkernel. Therefore, it provides access to arbitrary admin-type access, such as shutting down the server, stopping services, deploying new services, and so on. It should either be secured like any other web application or removed.

**The *web-console.war* Service**

The web-console.war found in the deploy/management directory is another web application view into the JMX microkernel. This uses a combination of an applet and an HTML view and provides the same level of access to admin functionality as the jmx-console.war. Therefore, it should either be secured or removed. The web-console.war contains commented-out templates for basic security in its WEB-INF/web.xml as well as commented-out setup for a security domain in WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml.

**The *http-invoker.sar* Service**

The http-invoker.sar found in the deploy directory is a service that provides RMI/HTTP access for EJBs and the JNDI Naming service. This includes a servlet that processes posts of marshaled org.jboss.invocation.Invocation objects that represent invocations that should be dispatched onto the MBeanServer. This effectively allows access to MBeans that support the detached invoker operation via HTTP because someone could figure out how to format an appropriate HTTP post. To secure this access point, you would need to secure the JMXInvokerServlet servlet found in the http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/ WEB-INF/web.xml descriptor. A secure mapping is defined for the /restricted/ JMXInvokerServlet path by default; to use it, you would simply have to remove the other paths and configure the http-invoker security domain setup in the http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml descriptor.

**The *jmx-invoker-adaptor-server.sar* Service**

The jmx-invoker-adaptor-server.sar is a service that exposes the JMX MBeanServer interface via an RMI-compatible interface, using the RMI/JRMP detached invoker service. Currently, the only way for this service to be secured would be to switch the protocol to RMI/HTTP and secure the http-invoker.sar as described in the previous section. In the future, this service will be deployed as an XMBean with a security interceptor that supports role-based access checks. If you are so inclined, you can set up this configuration today, following the procedure demonstrated in the section "[Version 3: Adding Security and Remote Access to the JNDIMap XMBean](http://book.soundonair.ru/java/ch02lev1sec4.html#ch02lev4sec16)" in [Chapter 2](http://book.soundonair.ru/java/ch02.html#ch02), "The JBoss JMX Microkernel."

Comment: these services is a part of Jboss 7.1.1 also?